# Why would ScreenPointToRay be pointing in the wrong direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, raycasting

I'm having trouble with getting a mouse event on a 3D object in Unity. MonoBehavior callbacks not responding, and ScreenPointToRay produces very strange results.

Using Unity 2021.3.12. I want to simply know when a 3d object is clicked. I tried using EventTrigger to no avail. I added this script, which also did nothing:

```
        void OnMouseDown()
        {
            Clicked.Invoke();
        }
```

So I added this bit to see what ScreenPointToRay thinks it's doing:

```
        private void Update()
        {
            Vector2 mousePosition = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.yellow);
            if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
            {
                print("mouse is down");
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10000f))
                {
                    print("hit it");
                }
            }
        }
```

And it shows the ray projecting way off into -X land. In this screen shot, I have a fairly empty 3d scene. One cube (with Box collider) is at 0 0 0, and camera at 0 0 -10. Pointer should be starting the ray at 0 0 -10 and have direction of 0 0 1, but look at it! It gets close to 0 0 1 if I move the pointer all the way to the top right of my screen (but not quite, still pointing down a little)
[image]

I must be missing something really basic.

Comment: I don't think it is `ScreenPointToRay` behaving strange but rather maybe the position providing strange values? Have you tried debugging every step and check at which point exactly the values stop to make sense? You have a single mouse device right? Or is there potentially a confusion? Note `The Input System does not currently support: Input from multiple mice at the platform level.`

Comment: New data: The camera was set to target 'both' eyes. When set to 'none' the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the Camera settings, 'target eye' set to anything but 'none' will cause this problem. Set to 'none' and it works as expected.